# how to resolve array issue of IMAP mail

Tags: php, imap

Receiving an array like:

```
 Array ( [0] => Details of Contact Made: [1] => ) 
 Array ( [0] => ABC
 abc@yahoo.co.in
 1234567890
       [1] => ) 
 Array ( [0] => I am interested in your Residential Plot. Please get in touch with me.
 Immediately
       [1] => )`
```

How to extract information :

```
ABC
abc@yahoo.co.in
1234567890
I am interested in your Residential Plot. Please get in touch with me.
Immediately
```

Please help. I've been searching for the last 5 days.

Comment: is that the actual dump of the array ?

Answer (score 0):

you can implode the "inputArray", to get ah single string, when I have understand your question right.

For Example:

```
<?php

// $inputArray = 
/*
Array ( [0] => Details of Contact Made: [1] => ) Array ( [0] => ABC
abc@yahoo.co.in
1234567890
[1] => ) Array ( [0] => I am interested in your Residential Plot. Please get in touch with me.
Immediately
[1] => )
*/

$extractedInformation = implode(" ", $inputArray);
var_dump($extractedInformation);

?>
```